# Python equality statement of the form a==b in [c,d,e]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just came across some python code with the following statement:

```
if a==b in [c,d,e]:
    ...
```

It turns out that:

```
>>> 9==9 in [1,2,3]
False
>>> 9==9 in [1,2,3,9]
True
>>> (9==9) in [1,2,3,9]
True
>>> 9==(9 in [1,2,3,9])
False
>>> True in [1,2,3,9]
True
>>> True in []
False
>>> False in []
False
>>> False in [1,2,3]
False
```

Am I right in assuming that `a==b in [c,d,e]` is equivalent to `(a==b) in [c,d,e]` and therefore only really makes sense if `[c,d,e]` is a list of True/False values?

And in the case of the code I saw `b` is always in the list `[c,d,e]`. Would it then be equivalent to simply using `a==b`?

Comment: "Am I right in assuming that a==b in [c,d,e] is equivalent to (a==b) in [c,d,e]" - your own tests contradict that hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I right in assuming that `a==b in [c,d,e]` is equivalent to `(a==b) in [c,d,e]`

No. Since both `==` and `in` are [comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), the expression

```
a == b in [c, d, e]
```

is equivalent to

```
(a == b) and (b in [c, d, e])
```

since all comparison operators have the same precedence but can be chained.

> and therefore only really makes sense if `[c,d,e]` is a list of `True`/`False` values?

It can also make sense to check if a boolean value is contained in a list of integers. Since `True` is considered equivalent to `1`, and `False` is considered equivalent to `0` (see [The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)), the result of this check can even be `True`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to throw another factor into the mix, operator chaining needs to be [kept in mind as well](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Formally, if a, b, c, …, y, z are expressions and op1, op2, …, opN are comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.

The docs there specify "comparison operators", but later down is the addition:

> Note that comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, **all have the same precedence and have a left-to-right chaining feature as described in the Comparisons section**.

For example, `9==9 in [1,2,3,9]` is confusingly the same as `9==9 and 9 in [1, 2, 3, 9]`.

Comment: @CryptoFool Yes, this is a weird one, so I'm not surprised it was overlooked. IMO, they designed the chaining to be far too permissive. It's kind of ridiculous that my example snippets are the same. I personally think they should have forced chaining to only apply within "operator categories, or even not include membership tests in the chaining.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what is happening here, is that python interprets the values `1, 1.0, True` all as equal in this case. So as long as the `1` is present in the list, the `in` operator returns `True` when comparing against a statement that compiles to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

`a == b in [c,d,e]` means `( a == b ) and (b in [c,d,e])`

`True in [1,2,3]` means `1 in [1,2,3]` (`True == 1`)

`False in [0]` means `0 in [0]` (`False == 0`)

---

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
> to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
> cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if a, b, c, …, y, z are expressions and op1, op2, …, opN are
> comparison operators, then a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z is equivalent to
> a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z, except that each expression is
> evaluated at most once.
>
> Note that a op1 b op2 c doesn’t imply any kind of comparison between a
> and c, so that, e.g., x < y > z is perfectly legal (though perhaps not
> pretty).

[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

---

The new Assignment expression (:=) operator from Python 3.8 onwards has the lowest precedence while parentheses() have the highest precedence.

| Operator | Description |
| --- | --- |
| := | Assignment expression (Lowest precedence) |
| lambda | Lambda expression |
| if-else | Conditional expression |
| or | Boolean OR |
| and | Boolean AND |
| not x | Boolean NOT |
| <, <=, >, >=, | Comparison operators |
| !=, == | Equality operators |
| in, not in, is, is not, | Identity operators, membership |
| | | Bitwise OR |
| ^ | Bitwise XOR |
| & | Bitwise AND |
| <<, >> | Left and right Shifts |
| +, – | Addition and subtraction |
| *, @, /, //, % | Multiplication, matrix multiplication, division, floor division, remainder |
| +x, -x, ~x | Unary plus, Unary minus, bitwise NOT |
| ** | Exponentiation |
| await x | Await expression |
| x[index], x[index:index], x(arguments…), x.attribute | Subscription, slicing, call, attribute reference |
| (expressions…), [expressions…],{key: value…}, {expressions…} | Binding or parenthesized expression, list display, dictionary display, set display |
| () | Parentheses (Highest precedence) |